# Retrieve the URL for a Google Spreadsheet using Zend

Tags: google-sheets, zend-gdata, google-sheets-api

We have a form that submits data to various Google Spreadsheets using Zend Gdata. I'd like to be able to display the URL to the spreadsheet the data was submitted after the submit process finishes. I can't seem to find anyway to retrieve the URL for the doc though. It seems like this should be a simple function but I can't seem to find anything about how to do this anywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you actually connect and submit data to the spreadsheet, you should get a  spreadsheet entry back from that submission process. On that entry you can get all links or any link.

```
$entry->getLink(); this will give you all links, bear in mind a link is an internal "Google" link reference its not always a link as we know it.

//the link you will want for distributing is probably something like:
$entry->getLink('self');
```